# google apps script to create new pdf document of updated cells after form submission and email this pdf error message:

Tags: forms, pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Please bear with me as I am very much a beginner at this. I am trying to write a Google script which creates a new spreadsheet of the relevant data after a form is submitted, converts this to a PDF, and sends it as an email attachment to an email address which is submitted to the form. I am writing the code in a script which is bound to the sheet which performs some calculations on the data once it is submitted. The form is also bound to the sheet. I will paste my code below and here is a link to the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oQTeQFwl7IfWF8D17oK1Mutp4TXidQXUT4lv46ktuwM/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to email the small green summary section on the sheet named INPUTS/OUTPUTS as a pdf.

The Template file "MyCalculations" is just an empty spreadsheet apart from one line saying "here are your calculation results". 
The summary section updates itself well and correctly after a form is submitted I am just having real trouble accessing the sheet because I can't code!

Here is the code so far:

```
function onFormSubmit(e){

//Variables
var userEmail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H24").getValue();
var totalOutstandingPrincipalDebt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G22").getValue();
var totalOutstandingInterest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H22").getValue();
var totalOutstandingCompensation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("I22").getValue();
var dailyInterestRate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("J22").getValue();
var grandTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G23").getValue();

var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFilesByName("MyCalculations");

//Template Info
var docName="Calculations";
var copyDoc= docTemplate.makeCopy();
var copyId = copyDoc.getId();
var copyBody = docTemplate.getActiveSection();

copyBody.getRange(2, 1).setValue("Total Outstanding Principal Debt");
copyBody.getRange(2, 2).setValue("Total Outstanding Interest");
copyBody.getRange(2, 3).setValue("Total Outstanding Compensation");
copyBody.getRange(2, 4).setValue("Grand Total");
copyBody.getRange(2, 5).setValue("Daily Interest Rate");
copyBody.getRange(3, 1).setValue(totalOutstandingPrincipalDebt);
copyBody.getRange(3, 2).setValue(totalOutstandingInterest);
copyBody.getRange(3, 3).setValue(totalOutstandingCompensation);
copyBody.getRange(3, 4).setValue(grandTotal);
copyBody.getRange(3, 5).setValue(dailyInterestRate);

//Save as PDF and send e-mail
var pdf = getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
var subject = "Calculations";
var body = "Thank you very much for using our online calculator. Please find your results attached.";
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
//Deletes temporary Document
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
```

}

I also don't think that in this code, I have specified which sheet on my spreadsheet I am wanting to get the data from, but I don't know how to do that either!

Any help would be so so appreciated!

Comment: I dont know, mustve been a bit out of mind when i added that tag, I've removed it now, thank you for bring it to my attention!

Answer (score 1):

`var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFilesByName("MyCalculations");`

`getFilesByName` returns a `FileIterator` not a `Spreadsheet` so you have to change that to:

`var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFilesByName("MyCalculations").next().getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);`

Next, in `var copyBody = docTemplate.getActiveSection();` there is no such method called `getActiveSection` change that to:

`var copyBody = docTemplate.getActiveSheet();`

Lastly, the line `var pdf = getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");`

should be

`var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");`

Implement those changes and let me know how it works. =)

**Update**

I fiddled around and as far as I can tell, DriveApp automatically converts almost all files to a PDF. So, as I understand it, you are using the MyCalculations spreadsheet as a template so that you can convert it into a PDF and send it.

We can accomplish this with a little bit of a roundabout way.

First, we create a new sheet in our original spreadsheet, and hide it from view so that the user can't see it.

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var myCalculations = spreadsheet.insertSheet("MyCalculations",spreadsheet.getNumSheets());
myCalculations.hideSheet();
```

Secondly, we set all the values that you want. So change

`copyBody.setRange` ...

to

`myCalculations.setRange` ...

Thirdly, once we have all our data set. We are going create a temporary Spreadsheet to copy all our data into so that we may export it as a PDF and send it in an email

`var tempSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Temporary');`

Fourth, we copy our calculations page into the temporary spreadsheet.

`myCalculations.copyTo(tempSpreadsheet);`

Perfect! Now we just convert the temporary spreadsheet into a PDF and do a little clean-up. Be sure to note the change to the line where we delete the temporary spreadsheet. I get the id by just calling the `getId()` method

```
var pdf = tempSpreadsheet.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
var subject = "Calculations";
var body = "Thank you very much for using our online calculator. Please find your results attached.";
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
//Deletes temporary Document
DriveApp.getFileById(tempSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

That should do the trick. Comment how it works for you. =)

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I implemented those changes but now I'm getting the following error message: "Converting from application/pdf to application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet is not supported. (line 13, file " 

Line 13 was: var docTemplate = DriveApp.getFilesByName("MyCalculations").next().getAs(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS); line

It's strange because MyCalculations is definitely a sheet not a pdf, and also i tried by commenting out the: .getAs("application/pdf") incase that was the problem but it didnt seem to make any difference. any ideas?

Comment: I edited the answer to offer a new solution. It's a bit convoluted but it should work (in theory). Let me know how it goes. =)

Comment: Thanks Misha! I actually managed to solve it yesterday too in a different way, I'll post my solution as an answer as well. I still need to figure out how to change the font and number of significant figures but I'm hoping I'll be able to figure them out without too much difficulty. Thanks so much again I really appreciate your help!

Comment: [var pdf = tempSpreadsheet.getAs(MimeType.PDF);] saved the day, thank you @Misha!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this code working:

```
//Set out global variables
var docTemplate = ("1Ff3SfcXQyGeCe8-Y24l4EUMU7P9TsgREsAYO9W6RE2o");
var docName=("Calculations");

function onFormSubmit(e){

//Variables
var userEmail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H24").getValue();
var totalOutstandingPrincipalDebt =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G22").getValue();
var totalOutstandingInterest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("H22").getValue();
var totalOutstandingCompensation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("I22").getValue();
var dailyInterestRate = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("J22").getValue();
var grandTotal = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G23").getValue();


//Template Info

var copyId=DriveApp.getFileById(docTemplate).makeCopy(docName+' for '+userEmail).getId();
var copyDoc = DocumentApp.openById(copyId);
var copyBody = copyDoc.getActiveSection();

//Putting the data into the file
copyBody.insertParagraph(0,'Total Outstanding Principal Debt: ' + totalOutstandingPrincipalDebt);
copyBody.insertParagraph(1,'Total Outstanding Interest: '+ totalOutstandingInterest );
copyBody.insertParagraph(2,'Total Outstanding Compensation: '+ totalOutstandingCompensation);
copyBody.insertParagraph(3,'Grand Total: ' + grandTotal);
copyBody.insertParagraph(4,'Daily Interest Rate: '+ dailyInterestRate);
copyDoc.saveAndClose();

 //email pdf document as attachment 
var pdf = DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).getAs("application/pdf");
var subject = "Calculations";
var body = "Thank you very much for using our online calculator. Please find your results attached.";
MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, body, {htmlBody: body, attachments: pdf});
//Deletes temporary Document
DriveApp.getFileById(copyId).setTrashed(true);
```

}